# How can I route audio through bluetooth in Android 2.0 and 2.1?

Tags: android, stream, bluetooth

I can do in in 2.2 by setting the stream type to STREAM_`VOICE`_CALL, then calling `setBluetoothScoOn(true)` and `startBluetoothSCO()`, but the `startBluetoothSCO()` method is only available in 2.2+. I'm probably supposed to use the deprecated `setRouting()` method, but I can't find any info on how to do that.

I would also like to stream A2DP, but have the same problem - `setBluetoothA2dpOn(true)` doesn't exist before 2.2.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.